# Python: Assign variable in JSON payload

Tags: python, python-3.x, api

I'm not able to pass the variable in the payload field.

```py
import requests

id = 567 # I want to use this variable ID in the payload filed.
url = "<URL>"
payload = "{\"settings\":{\"id\":\"123\"},\"uuid\":\"abc\"}"
```

I tried passing my id variable inside the payload filed using `"+ str(id) +"`

Still, it is not working

Please help me with this, I'm struggling with this for a very long time now.

Comment: Don't mangle strings to build JSON. Parse the JSON into a data structure, modify it there, and then dump it back out to a string.

Comment: You'll have to parse the JSON and then perhaps treat it like a dictionary. I recommend also using `import json` to help you.

Comment: Shadowing the builtin `id` symbol is a Bad Idea. Better to spell your variable like this: `id_`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
import requests
import json

id = 567 #i want to use this variable ID in the payload filed.
url = ""

payload = {
   "settings": {
      "id": "123"
               },
   "uuid": "abc"
           }

payload['settings']['id'] = id

headers = { 'accept': "application/json", 'content-type': "application/json", 'x-apikeys': "accessKey=key;secretKey=key" } 
response = requests.request("POST", url, json=payload, headers=headers) 
response.text()
```

Comment: I'm getting this error:

    payload['settings']['id'] = id
TypeError: string indices must be integers

Comment: had a missing " at start of settings in the dictionary setup. fixed now.

Comment: it is how it looks:
import requests
import json

id = 567 #i want to use this variable ID in the payload filed.
url = ""

    payload = "{\"settings\":{\"id\":\"123\"},\"uuid\":\"abc\"}"
    payload['settings']['id'] = id
    payload_as_string = json.dumps(payload)

    headers = {
        'accept': "application/json",
        'content-type': "application/json",
        'x-apikeys': "accessKey=key;secretKey=key"
    }

    response = requests.request("POST", url, data=payload, headers=headers)
    response.text()

Comment: @Rukender the comments do not maintain formatting.  better to add explanation via edit to your original post.

Comment: updated it to use json= argument.  no need to convert to string first, let request method do that for you

Comment: It now worked :) 
Thank you so much.

payload['settings']['id'] = id : This command is replacing the value of id. Does it mean that while defining the id in the payload I can give anything or keep it empty? or is there a way I can directly pass the variable?

Comment: Feel free to upvote the answer. Glad to help.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what your trying to do

```
import json
id = 567 #i want to use this variable ID in the payload filed.
url = ""
payload = "{\"settings\":{\"id\":\"123\"},\"uuid\":\"abc\"}"
py_dict = json.loads(payload)
py_dict['settings']['id'] = <ID>
payload = json.dumps(py_dict)
```

Comment: I'm getting this error:

    payload['settings']['id'] = id
TypeError: string indices must be integers

Comment: your supposed to index py_dict